# SF story about sharing tools and other possesions with RFID tags

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cyberpunk

I'm thinking of a story I read probably in *Asimov's* in the 1990s or early 2000s. There wasn't much plot, just an extended "what if" about being able to tag all your possessions with RFID chips, so if you lend a tool to a neighbor, it's always clear that it's yours. I think the story was by one of the authors known for cyberpunk in the 1980s. It was a fairly hopeful story - not dystopian.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Searched the isfdb pages of some cyberpunk and found [User-Centric](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?91952) by Bruce Sterling, conveniently online [here](https://bruces.medium.com/user-centric-by-bruce-sterling-1999-5bc22e365e82). Here's the passage I was remembering:

> If Al has the location and condition of all his possessions
> cybernetically tracked and tagged in real time, maybe Al is freed
> from worrying about all his stuff. Why should Al fret about his
> possessions any more? **We’ve made them permanently safe. For instance,
> why shouldn’t Al loan the lawnmower to his neighbor? Al’s neighbor
> can’t lose the lawnmower, he can’t sell it, he can’t steal it, because
> Al’s embedded MEMS monitors just won’t allow that behavior.**
>
> So now Al can be far more generous to his neighbor. Instead of being
> miserly and geeky — “labelling everything he possesses,” obsessed with
> possessiveness and privacy — Al turns out to be an open-handed, open-
> hearted, very popular guy. Al probably doesn’t even have locks on his
> doors any more. Al doesn’t need locks! Everything Al has is
> automatically theft-proof — thanks to us.
>
> I see Al throwing big house parties. Al is fearlessly showing off his
> home and his possessions. Everything that was once a personal burden
> to Al becomes a benefit to the neighborhood community. What was once
> Al’s weakness and anxiety is now a source of emotional strength and
> community esteem for Al.

I had totally forgotten the meta aspect of the story, in which what appears to be a team of marketers creating the character of Al as a way to understand potential customers is really a dream that Al wakes from, (symbolizing a bit of ambivalence about how his life has turned out?).

Comment: What is the meta aspect of the story? WTF is a "meta aspect" anyway?

Comment: Added a bit more